# Extracting countries from string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, gis, geopandas

I am trying to go through a column of data frame in python 3. What I need to do is take from each row the country that it is mentioned and the number of times that country is mentioned.
i.e. if I have this row:

```
['[Aydemir, Deniz', ' Gunduz, Gokhan', ' Asik, Nejla] Bartin Univ, Fac Forestry, Dept Forest Ind Engn, TR-74100 Bartin, Turkey', ' [Wang, Alice] Lulea Univ Technol, Wood Technol, Skelleftea, Sweden']
```

it needs to output a list: `['Turkey', 'Sweden']`

and if I have this row:

```
['[Fang, Qun', ' Cui, Hui-Wang] Zhejiang A&F Univ, Sch Engn, Linan 311300, Peoples R China', ' [Du, Guan-Ben] Southwest Forestry Univ, Kunming 650224, Yunnan, Peoples R China']
```

the output should be: `['China', 'China']`.

I have written this code but it is not working as I want to:

```
from geotext import GeoText
sentence = df.iloc[0,0]
places = GeoText(sentence)
print(places.countries)
```

It prints only the country once and in some cases when it is USA it doesn't recognize the abbreviation. Can you help me figure out what to do?

```
l = [['[Aydemir, Deniz\', \' Gunduz, Gokhan\', \' Asik, Nejla] Bartin Univ, Fac Forestry, Dept Forest Ind Engn, TR-74100 Bartin, Turkey\', \' [Wang, Alice] Lulea Univ Technol, Wood Technol, Skelleftea, Sweden',1990],
 ['[Fang, Qun\', \' Cui, Hui-Wang] Zhejiang A&F Univ, Sch Engn, Linan 311300, Peoples R China\', \' [Du, Guan-Ben] Southwest Forestry Univ, Kunming 650224, Yunnan, Peoples R China',2005],
 ['[Blumentritt, Melanie\', \' Gardner, Douglas J.\', \' Shaler, Stephen M.] Univ Maine, Sch Resources, Orono, ME USA\', \' [Cole, Barbara J. W.] Univ Maine, Dept Chem, Orono, ME 04469 USA',2012]]
dataf = pd.DataFrame(l, columns = ['Authors', 'Year'])
```

I tried to do this code but I have the same problem, it doesn't give all the counties only one per row:

```
def find_country(n):
    for c in pycountry.countries:
        if str(c.name).lower() in n.lower():
            return c.name
country1 = (dataf['Authors']
  .replace(r"\bUSA\b", "United States", regex=True)
  .apply(lambda x: find_country(x)))
```

Comment: Please show the actual dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USA does not seem to be detected correctly by geotext - it's worth trying to raise an issue with that package. As a workaround here, I replace USA with United States, which is correctly detected.

```
df = (dataf['Authors']
      .replace(r"\bUSA\b", "United States", regex=True)
      .apply(lambda x: geotext.GeoText(x).countries)
)
```

I'm not sure what you were doing before, but this will get the list of countries for each of the rows in Author, including duplicates.

```
0                  [Turkey, Sweden]
1                    [China, China]
2    [United States, United States]
Name: Authors, dtype: object
```

As mentioned in the comment, if you want to have an actual list of lists, just add `tolist()` to the end.

```
df.tolist()

[['Turkey', 'Sweden'], ['China', 'China'], ['United States', 'United States']]
```

Comment: I like the solution very much. But how can I turn this code into giving me a list of lists for each row: `[[Turkey, Sweden],[China, China],[United States, United States]]`?

Comment: `result_dataframe = dataf['Authors'].replace...`  
`result_list = result_dataframe.values.tolist()`

Comment: @mandella I have updated with how to convert to a list of lists.

Comment: Thank you both @jberrio

Comment: Do you perhaps know any other package that is better than geotext? It doesn't recognize England, North Ireland, Wales and probably some more plus when they are written in all upper or lower case letters it doesn't work. I was checking for a solution a lot but couldn't  find any.

Comment: I tried to do something else. I posted the code above but still no success.